# Get the last(latest) process pid in linux

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, command

I want to get the last/latest process pid in linux.Can anyone suggest me the command to find that ? But I don't know which process has started last.

Comment: You want to know the last process called and always running or the last process killed ?

Comment: Maybe not an ideal answer, but here's what I found on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/250066/the-easiest-method-to-get-the-pid-of-last-process .

Comment: The last process in the system will in most cases be the one you have started to find out what the last process is. Perhaps you need a better defined notion of last

Comment: this is some sort of process monitoring, I am handling.  I wanted to know, is there any command which tells me latest process started in the process pool and not the search process that I am going to search the latest process.

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** Thanks to William for the hint about awk. 
**Pre-condition:** The process has still to be running.

I am not an UNIX expert, but I thought about the following approach:

```
ps aux --sort +start_time | tail -n 4 | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'
```

`ps` will list all processes and we are going to sort them by start_time. Afterwards we are going to take the fourth from the last line [0] of the output and awk will return the pid found in the second field.

```
root@unix ~ % sleep 10 &
[1] 3009
root@unix ~ % ps aux --sort +start_time | tail -n 4 | awk 'NR==1{print $2 " " $11}'
3009 sleep
root@unix ~ %
```

---

[0] The fourth line because there are three piped commands in my commandline.

Comment: No need for `head`.  Use `awk 'NR==1{...}` instead.

Comment: There is a huge race condition here, and this will often fail to produce meaningful results.

Comment: Yup ... I have used meisterluk technique and changed the command according to my requirement.

Comment: Does somebody know the BSD/MacOS equivalent of `ps --sort`? The code in this answer is not portable.

Comment: @rien333 Maybe something like `ps aux | sort -r -k9 - | awk 'NR==3{print $2}'` works? Trying to help, but it seems very cumbersome on BSD.

Comment: This is really nice but how can we list the last 10 processes that were started last?

Comment: @user63274 `ps aux --sort +start_time | tail -n 14 | head -n 10 | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 6):

If you want the process ID of the most recently executed background command you can use the ! variable. For example:

```
 > gvim text.txt &
 > echo $!
 2842
```

Answer (score 3):

Get `PID`:

```
#!/bin/bash
my-app & echo $!
```

Save `PID` in variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
my-app & export APP_PID=$!
```

Save all instances `PID` in text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
my-app & echo $! >>/tmp/my-app.pid
```

Save output, errors and `PID` in separated files:

```
#!/bin/bash
my-app >/tmp/my-app.log 2>/tmp/my-app.error.log & echo $! >>/tmp/my-app.pid

echo "my-app PID's: $(cat /tmp/my-app.pid)"
```